# Error calling simple stored procedure to create text log file

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure to write text out to a log file.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WriteTextFileLog]
    @TextForLog nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @CMDTEXT as nvarchar(255)

    SELECT @CMDTEXT = 'echo ' + @TextForLog + ' >> "\\pathtotextfile\LogFile.txt"'

    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CMDTEXT;
```

When I call it like this:

```
MYDATABASE.dbo.writetextfilelog  @TextForLog = CONVERT(varchar(23), GETDATE, 121)
```

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'

I must be missing something obvious...any ideas?

Comment: Missing () after `GETDATE`.  `GETDATE()`

Comment: Also: the `EXEC` command doesn't like expressions and such - you might need to do the `CONVERT` stuff before the `EXEC` call and store the results into a variable that you then pass to the `EXEC` - plain, without any expressions and calculations in the call ...

Comment: Thanks SCSIMON, I caught that...
 
MARC, I suspect you may be right, but I'm having trouble coding that...
  
MTB.dbo.writetextfilelog @TextForLog = "Blah blah test " + CONVERT(varchar(23), GETDATE(), 121)
  
I thought something like this would do it, but apparently not

Comment: @Brian, Why do you even need a paramter if it's just a GetDate()? Just declare that inside the stored procedure and remove the parameter.

Comment: hi WEI...well, it's not always going to be the date, I want to be able to pass any text to the SP so I can write it out to a text file as a log

Answer (score 1):

As @marc_s said in the comments, [`EXECUTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188332.aspx) doesn't accept expressions as parameter values, only plain constant string or variable or `DEFAULT` keyword.

Here is the command's syntax for calling a stored procedure:

> ```
> [ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]  
>     {   
>       [ @return_status = ]  
>       { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var }   
>         [ [ @parameter = ] { value   
>                            | @variable [ OUTPUT ]   
>                            | [ DEFAULT ]   
>                            }  
>         ]  
>       [ ,...n ]  
>       [ WITH <execute_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
>     }  
> [;]
> ```

So, prepare the value of the parameter in advance in a variable:

```
DECLARE @VarText nvarchar(max);
SET @VarText = N'Blah blah test ' + CONVERT(varchar(23), GETDATE(), 121);
EXEC MYDATABASE.dbo.writetextfilelog @TextForLog = @VarText;
```

I'd recommend you to use `nvarchar(max)` sparingly, only when you really need more than 4000 characters. Otherwise use a sensible limit, like `nvarchar(255)`.

Comment: That explains it perfectly Vladimir, works great, thanks very much for your help! My brain got stuck!  :-D